# What is the etymology of the word "Shawshank"?

Tags: etymology

What is the etymology of the word "Shawshank" from the movie "The Shawshank Redemption" and from the original Stephen King book, "Rita Hayworth and Shawshank Redemption"?

Comment: The Shawshank Redemption, is named after the mythical Maine town that provides the setting for many of King’s books. https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/57589/15-things-you-may-not-have-known-about-shawshank-redemption - https://www.google.com/search?q=shawshank+maine&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&oq=shawshank+maine&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.6461j0j7&hl=it&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Kinda like saying the origin for the movie is the book. But where did King get the name?

Comment: I guess he just made it up.

Comment: That is what I am trying to find out. Do you have a source with that info?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-word-Shawshank-mean

Comment: I'm guessing that the word sounded to King like a Native American name -- it's not at all strange sounding for a place name in parts of the US where Native American naming was commonly used.

Comment: (And, of course, having "shank" in the name seemed appropriate for a prison.)

Comment: Another guess would be that "Shawshank" was the surname of one of the fictitious early settlers in the area that became the fictitious town.

Comment: https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/13732/where-did-stephen-king-get-the-word-shawshank-from

Comment: It could be based on the native American name [Shawsheen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shawsheen), which King is likely to have heard, but purely a guess.

Answer (score -2):

"Shashank" is a well-known Hindu boy's name in India. "Shashank" is Sanskrit; it refers to the new moon. Its significance lies in the fact that Lord Shiva wears the new moon - shashank - as a head-dress.

Where American author Stephen King found the "w" for his fictional Maine town of this name, I do not know.

The ancient language of India, Sanskrit, dates back more than seven thousand years. The ancient mythology of India is written in Sanskrit and many of its kings, queens, heroes and characters are traditionally worshipped as gods, often with entire temples devoted to the worship of one in particular.

Comment: P.S. The ancient language of India, Sanskrit, dates back more than seven thousand years. The ancient mythology of India is written in Sanskrit and many of its kings, queens,heroes and characters are traditionally worshipped as gods, often with entire temples devoted to the worship of one in particular.

Comment: ... but without evidence, it seems far-fetched that King used this for the book.

Comment: And Sanskrit goes back only about 4000 years, and it is the source of Northern Indian languages and cultures. Southern India is another matter.

Comment: +1 I think "the word Shashank exists in X language" is as good an argument as anyone else has offered.